# Advice on Backup Domain Controller O/S

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

Looking for a recommendation on which of my servers to put a secondary DC in case PDC is down.

Physical Servers:

1 x Windows Server 2008 R2 running AD, DHCP, DNS, WSUS.
 2 x Windows Server 2008 R2 in a FailoverCluster as Hyper-V hosts.

Virtual Servers (3 on each host, host has capacity to take all 6 on a failover so not looking to add any more servers)

1. Server 2003 running legacy SQL 2000 and IIS
2. Server 2008 R2 running SQL 2008
3. XP running a legacy app / sandbox machine
4. Server 2008 running Exchange 2007
5. Server 2008 R2 running IIS 7 for .net web apps
6. Server 2008 print server and AV administrative console.

Comment: How about adding AD to virtual server 6 (print server and AV admin)?  That seems to be the best choice from the details you give, unless there are some other factors not listed...

Comment: That was my feeling too but I was cautious about using Server 2008 over 2008 R2.  Any good guides advice for adding this DC?  Also, pop your comment in a question and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Well you could upgrade that server to R2.  But I don't know if that virtual server instance is running x64, which is required for R2.

Comment: I think it isn't R2 due to print driver issue.  I'm going to follow http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753720(WS.10).aspx and give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the way I would go.  Just DCPROMO that sucker and who cares if its R2.  You just want another copy of the AD schema in case your main DC tanks.  Your virtual server 6 looks like the perfect place to do this.